# How to implement token based authentication with Jakarta EE 9.1, Wildfly 26, JWT and plain Javascript with the fetch API?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, jwt, wildfly, fetch-api

I use Java 17, Jakarta EE 9.1 with Wildfly 26.1.1 Preview (Jakarta EE compatible) on the server side. I use HTML, CSS and plain Javascript with no third party library (except zip.js but it's unrelated) on the client side. I've tried to find a working example, [the most helpful source I've found is in Wildfly's quickstart](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/main/jaxrs-jwt).

However, the client code doesn't cover my case even though it's useful to test in command line. How should I use the JSON web token in Javascript and HTML? What are the good practices to achieve that in terms of security? I use HTTPS and I plan to sign and encrypt the tokens with an asymmetric algorithm (RSA, elliptic curves), the secret key would remain on the server, the public key would be sent by the server to the client, only the server would be able to decrypt the tokens as long as the secret key isn't compromised.

For now, this is what I have done so far:
I use an HTML form, I can either use HTTP POST and a form action to pass the username and the encrypted password, both are URL encoded, the server knows the referrer and uses a redirection with [Response.seeOther​(URI)](https://javadoc.io/static/jakarta.platform/jakarta.jakartaee-api/10.0.0/jakarta/ws/rs/core/Response.html#seeOther(java.net.URI)) to implement the POST/redirect/GET pattern or I can use the attribute "onsubmit" of the form to call a Javascript method that performs an asynchronous fetch request using the HTTP POST method with the fetch API and returns false to prevent the validation, the server doesn't use a redirect, it returns the signed and encrypted JSON web token with an expiry date on success. I currently use the second approach, are they equivalent in terms of security?

Now that I have the JSON web token, I have to use the fetch API to put this token into the HTTP header each time I have to access to a potentially protected resource: Authorization: Bearer <JWT>. If things go well, the server will reply HTTP 200 OK and will return the resource in the body.

I plan to store the token in the client side locally in the Javascript code (the main part of my webapp is in a single web page), I will use neither localStorage nor sessionStorage nor a secure cookie. I'll probably use localStorage, sessionStorage or a service worker where I need to handle several pages as in [this example](https://gaurav-techgeek.medium.com/re-architecting-authentication-with-service-workers-ff8fbbbfbdeb).

Am I on the good road? Sorry for the newbie question, it's the very first time I use token based authentication.

Please note that I won't use Spring, JQuery, Vue, Angular, etc. I need to understand the concepts and their implications in terms of security.

P.S: I'll have to implement mostly the same kind of authentication with Jetty >= 11. Therefore, Jetty specific solutions are welcome too.

Comment: The Quickstart you link would now require WildFly 27 which is Jakarta EE 10. WildFly 26.1.1.Final is Jakarta EE 8. If you want to use Jakarta EE 9.1, which I would NOT suggest, you'd need to use WildFly Preview 26.1.1.Final which is Jakarta EE 9.1 compatible.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins You're right, this is what I do, I have no choice as I use a workaround to disable failure on empty beans in Jackson that works on Wildfly 26.1.1 Preview but not with Wildfly 27 (it complained about a conflict between JAXB and Jackson).

Comment: There should be a version of Jackson that works with Jakarta XML Binding that is provided in WildFly 27.

Comment: It works with 75% of my web services as is but I have to disable FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS to make the others work too, which doesn't work with Wildfly 27. Actually, I have found 3 other problems that prevent me from switching. The JDBC driver has to be put into two locations because of a new feature using SQL array in Hibernate 6, I haven't found the second location.

Comment: *Why* do you want to use token-based authentication instead of standard session cookies? Do you understand the trade-offs? How do you perform logout? How do you forcibly log out a user?

Comment: In particular, consider https://gist.github.com/samsch/0d1f3d3b4745d778f78b230cf6061452 and http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: At least one of my projects must work without cookies for legal and technical reasons, it would be a bit annoying to ask end users the right to store cookies only for authentication. I understand the trade-offs, I'll have to violate the stateless principle to invalidate tokens before expiry date, I'll have to renew the tokens somehow, it's not standard but computer science requires compromises.